# PHP code not updating SQL database although print_r suggests correct input

Tags: php, mysql

First of all this is my first question on here, and altohugh I have searched the site none of the answers I've seen resolve my current problem.

I am a PHP novice and am currently working on an end project for a course. The object is to make a rudimentary blog where users can post, delete and edit their news, admins can edit or delete everything etc. I am mostly doing fine, but am having a bit of trouble with the editing feature.

The following code displays all blog posts, their authors and dates of posting. If the currently logged in person is the author of a post or a admin, they have the option of deleting or editing each individual post. A small form appears that contains the title and post text. When the user types something else in clicking on the edit button should change the values in the database to the new values the user specified. The problem is that whenever i click on the edit button in the current setup, nothing happens. If i move the if statement outside of the other if statement, the posts do update, but become blank in the database.

Running print_r($_POST) after the fact shows that the array it builds has correct names and updated values, but still they aren't updated in the database. Here is the code, the pertinent part starts at the last if statement( I know, it isn't injection proof, will get to that as soon as it works):

```
$query = "SELECT id, title, body, pub_date, user_id FROM posts ORDER BY id desc";
$query_fetch = mysql_query($query);

while ($blog_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_fetch)) {
                $author_id = $blog_post["user_id"];
                $post_id = $blog_post["id"];
                $post_id2 = $blog_post["id"] . 2;
                $title = $blog_post['title'];
                $body = $blog_post['body'];
                $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = '$author_id'";
                $query_run = mysql_query($query);
                $author = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run);

                echo "<h2>" . censor($blog_post["title"]) . "</h2>" . "<br> <p> Autor: " . $author["username"] . "</p><br><p>Objavljeno: " . $blog_post["pub_date"];
                        if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1 or $_SESSION['username'] == $author["username"]) {

                        echo "<form action='' method='POST'><input type='submit' name= '$post_id' value= 'Obriši objavu'></form>";
                        echo "<form action='' method='POST'><input type='submit' name= '$post_id2' value= 'Uredi objavu'></form>";
                }
                echo "<p>" . censor($blog_post["body"]) . "</p>";

                                if (isset($_POST["$post_id"])) {
                                $del_post = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = '$post_id'";
                                mysql_query($del_post);
                                }
                                if (isset($_POST["$post_id2"])) {
                                        echo "<form action='' method= 'POST'>New title<input type='text' value = '$title' name='title'>New text<textarea name='body' id='' cols='30' rows='10'>$body</textarea><input type='submit' name='edit' value='edit'></form>"; 
                                                if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
                                                $edit_title = $_POST['title'];
                                                $edit_body = $_POST['body'];
                                                $query = "UPDATE posts SET title= '$edit_title', body= '$edit_body' WHERE id= '$post_id'";
                                                mysql_query($query);
                                }
                        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: first time to this site, novice in php.... its sounds symptom of lack of understanding php is it ? But I impressed with your nick name

Comment: Just put $post_id =1; and compile

Comment: @Arshid KV - I must confess that I don't understand your answer completely. First of all, how would setting $post_id to 1 help? The table has a unique id for every post, and I want to change each individual post by clicking on that post's edit button. That's why the variable can't be fixed. Also, how do i compile PHP code? We haven't touched on that, just writing it in an editor and running the files  on a local host.

Comment: `$query = "UPDATE posts SET title= '$edit_title', body= '$edit_body' WHERE id= '$post_id'";`
Does `$query` here contains correct values?  What does `mysql_error()` says?

Comment: @PHP_newb001 I have an answer for you down below. I didn't check your SQL though.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, They're deprecated and no longer maintained. Your code also is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: The edit form does not contain back $post_id2, so the EDIT UPDATE actually never gets executed. Add an input with $post_id2 in the last FORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This last piece of code

```
if (isset($_POST["$post_id2"])) {
    echo "<form action='' method= 'POST'>New title<input type='text' value = '$title' name='title'>New text<textarea name='body' id='' cols='30' rows='10'>$body</textarea><input type='submit' name='edit' value='edit'></form>"; 
    if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
        $edit_title = $_POST['title'];
        $edit_body = $_POST['body'];
        $query = "UPDATE posts SET title= '$edit_title', body= '$edit_body' WHERE id= '$post_id'";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

gets activated when post_id2 is sent, but generates a form where post_id2 is not contained anymore. So when you submit that form, the IF is not entered.

You can modify it like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["$post_id2"])) {
    echo "<form action='' method= 'POST'>New title<input type='text' value = '$title' name='title'>New text<textarea name='body' id='' cols='30' rows='10'>$body</textarea><input type='submit' name='edit' value='edit'></form>";
}
if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {
    $edit_title = $_POST['title'];
    $edit_body = $_POST['body'];
    $query = "UPDATE posts SET title= '$edit_title', body= '$edit_body' WHERE id= '$post_id'";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

In general I think you would find it easier to use forms differently, specifically by using some sort of action tag:

```
input type="hidden" name="command" value="edit"
input type="hidden" name="post" value="{$post_id}"
```

This way you could run one single query immediately, without the need for browsing all the posts in a cycle.

One other useful possibility is to split your code between different PHP files, and keeping common code in one include:

```
<?php // this is delete.php
    include "common.php";
    $post_id = my_get_var('post_id');
    my_sql_command("DELETE FROM posts WHERE...");
```

used from

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post" ...>
```

As you can see this allows for different ways of retrieving post_id (centrally defined in a single function my_get_var in common.php) and the central definition of SQL functions. *How* this function interfaces to MySQL can then be updated, specifically passing from mysql_ functions (which are deprecated, and soon will no longer be available) to e.g. PDO.

It also allows you to test a single command independently, by directly entering delete.php in the browser (you need for my_get_var to accept both POST and GET variables to do this).

## Details

You want to inspect and/or modify a collection of posts. You then require initially at least the following operations: list, edit, and delete.

Only the first works against all posts.

So you could have a list.php file running the SELECT. Also, it is only in this SELECT that you need information about the user, so your query could become:

```
$query = "SELECT posts.id, title, body, pub_date, user_id, username FROM posts JOIN users ON (posts.user_id = users.id) ORDER BY posts.id desc";
```

In the display cycle we would display this information:

```
$query_fetch = mysql_query($query);

// This file will receive requests to edit or delete
// We can use a single form.
echo '<form action="manage.php">';

while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_fetch)) {

    echo "<h2>" . censor($post["title"]) . "</h2>" . "<br> <p> Autor: " . $post["username"] . "</p><br><p>Objavljeno: " . $post["pub_date"];
    if ((1 == $_SESSION['admin']) or ($_SESSION['username'] == $post["username"]) {
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Obriši objavu\" value=\"{$post['id']}\" />";
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Uredi objavu\" value=\"{$post['id']}\" />";
    }
    echo "<p>" . censor($blog_post["body"]) . "</p>";
}
echo "</form>";
```

This way you need only one form, and it will submit one field with a name describing the action to be taken, and the post on which to do it.

The file manage.php will then receive this information -- and can also be used to update it:

```
foreach(array(
    "delete" => "Obriši objavu", // from list.php
    "edit" => "Uredi objavu", // " "
    "update" => "update" // from this file itself (see below)
  )
    as $test_todo => $var) {
    if (array_key_exists($var, $_POST)) {
        $id   = $_POST[$var];
        $todo = $test_todo;
    }
}
if (isset($id)) {
    switch($todo) {
        case "delete":
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = '{$id}'");
            break;
        case "edit":
            // Get this post.
            $query = "SELECT posts.id, title, body, pub_date, user_id, username FROM posts JOIN users ON (posts.user_id = users.id) WHERE posts.id = '{$id}';";
            echo '<form action="manage.php" method= "POST">';
            // This is how we tell this file what to do, and to what.
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"update\" value=\"{$id}\">";
            // run query, fetch the one record, display info...
            echo "</form>";
            break;
      case "update":
            // Build the update query from $_POST.
            mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET ...");
  }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your in-depth response Iserni. I tried your first solution already. What that does is it executes the code for every iteration of the while loop instead for one individual post. The newly entered title and body then get copied to every entry since the loop rings up every post id. The code should only execute once, for the individual post where the individual editing button has been pressed. I will also take your other suggestions into account, but wil need to get a better grasp on them first. Also, what kind of input would you suggest i use in that last form?

Answer (score 0):

At first check that your query is correct. Then try to hard-code your query. Also test your query in `phpMyAdmin` Also you can try to remove the `''` from your `number` variables on every query.

Please, can you give us your error?

There is a possibility also that your database has already been updated. So double check it.

Comment: Check my conversation with Kishur. I am not getting any kind of input i could pass to MySQL when echoing it inside that if statement. When outside of the statement, it echoes correctly and alters data correctly, but does so for every iteration of the loop. It's like something is preventing the if statement from executing.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually debug. `echo` the query. Run it in PHPmyadmin, and see the error.

so, in your case.

`echo "UPDATE posts SET title= '$edit_title', body= '$edit_body' WHERE id= '$post_id'";`

`echo` that and you will have the query that the script will be trying to run.

Try running it in phpmyadmin and check what the error is.

Comment: What i get there is :#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'echo "UPDATE posts SET title= '$edit_title', body= '$edit_body' WHERE id= '$post' at line 1  But the code executes when i put it out of that last if statement, the db updates "correctly" but all posts are updated, not just the specific one so the syntax shouldn't be wrong

Comment: You got me wrong. I just updated the answer for a better understanding. comment out the query line, and add this line to your script, and run your script. You will have an output, which is the actually query that is going to be run. Copy that, and try it in phpmyadmin, and see what the error is.

Comment: Ah, my bad. But, like i said the code runs only outside of the last if statement.  If i echo what you said there it goes something like  "UPDATE posts SET title= 'test title', body= 'something' WHERE id= '11'". BUT, it does so for EVERY post, meaning that it echoes it as many times as there are posts with the id part changing to 12, then 13, then 14 etc, but the text stays the same, meaning it does access each individual post, but replaces them all with same info. What i need is to find a way to replace only the one post with new data i would like to add.

Comment: Continued...If i insert the code into that last if statement, nothing gets executed whatsoever. i don't understand what I am doing wrong since the logic appears to be sound, to me at least.

Comment: Instead of assuming it should be like that for every query, why not run a test like I said? What if its a character in the title that is breaking it? Are you  not using `escape` functions? Just try what I said. Post the generated query and the error that you will be getting.

Comment: I would like to do that @Kishor but the fact of the matter is that i CAN'T. Like i said, if i put that part of the code inside the if statement if (isset($_POST["$post_id2"])) nothing gets executed. The echo simply doesn't work, so i have no instructions to pass to the database. On the other had, i copied one of the echoes that pressing the button generated when the code was outside of the if statement, and that worked normally for the particular row which happened to correspond to that iteration of the  $user_id  variable.

Comment: `(isset($_POST["$post_id2"]))` - Thats plain wrong. why is a $ symbol inside the array index.?

Comment: Because that is the only way i could think of to name each individual button that the while loop generates. This way each button has a name that corresponds to the id of the post it is supposed to edit. It works perfectly for the button that deletes an individual post. I don't know if that is the cause of the problem, but if you know of a better  way to generate an individual name for every button I will be happy to try it out.

Comment: No, sorry, I read it wrong. I mean about the $ in the index. Well, about the error, I cant really help unless you manually try the query. Sorry.

Comment: Oh well, thank you for your persistence at least. I don't think there is an error in the query though. My impression is that something is preventing the if statement from going through when placed in the other statement.